# Trying to start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've cd in app root directory, and ran rails s. Then I get the error:

> Could not find gem 'rbczmq' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Installing the gem manually, with `gem install rbczmq`, had no success because of this:

> ERROR:  Error installing rbczmq:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /home/iulian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> "./autogen.sh"
>   autogen.sh: error: could not find libtool.  **libtool** is required to run autogen.sh.
>   ZeroMQ autogen failed!
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  **Check the mkmf.log file for more details**.  You may
>   need configuration options.

Then, I presumed that it needs **libtool**. I've tried to install it but it prompted that it is installed under the most recent version.
I've search lastly that file, **mkmf.log** under the path *~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rbczmq/ext/mkmf.log* but with no success. In the others installed gems directories this file exists, so I suppose that I don't find it in this problematic gem because it hasn't finished installing.

This app is programmed using rails 4, and I am trying to run it using Rails 5. This is also the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'rbczmq'
gem 'iruby'
gem 'spring', group: :development

gem 'elasticsearch-persistence', :require => 'elasticsearch/persistence'
```

Which could be the problem and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem once. Do this

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```